# Find range of filled contents in Excel worksheet

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I have an Excel 2016 `Book.xlsm`. In the worksheet `testsheet`, the cells in the range `A1:Y150` are filled with text or number contents. The upper-left cell is always `A1`.

I am using python v3 xlwings to open the Excel file.

```
import xlwings as xw
Book_name = 'C:/Users/name/Book.xlsm'
sheet_name = 'testsheet'
wb = xw.Book(Book_name)
sht = wb.sheets[sheet_name]
```

How do I find out the range of cells that are filled with contents using python, which in this case is `A1:Y150`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `wb` is defined as Excel Workbook, then this is a good way:

`print (wb.sheets[sheet_name].api.UsedRange.Address)`

Comment: I got the error `AttributeError: 'Sheet' object has no attribute 'UsedRange'`. May I ask if your code is vba or python xlwings?

Comment: @user1315789 - vba accesses and manipulates the Excel object, Python does the same. Excel is not open source, thus whatever is found there should be found in the Python/Java/C++ libraries etc. (At least my understanding).

Comment: Accessing the `api` is not cross-platfrom. I believe `UsedRange` is defined in `pywin32`, got no idea how it is defined in `appscript`. The other answer is safer.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the range filled with contents with [used_range](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=used_range#xlwings.Sheet.used_range):

```
import xlwings as xw

filename = "test.xlsx"

wb = xw.Book(filename)
ws = wb.sheets["SheetX"]
a_range = ws.used_range.address
print(a_range)
```