# How to achieve something like VBA's "Range.Find" using win32?

Tags: python, excel

I'm looking to achieve functionality similar to [the Range.Find method in VBA](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) using win32com package in Python. I'm dealing with an Excel CSV file. While I have found lots of solutions using `range()`, it seems to require specifying a fixed range of cells, as opposed to `Range.Find` in VBA, which will auto search in worksheet without fixing the range.

Here is my code:

```
import win32com.client as client

excel= client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.visible= True

wb= excel.workbooks.open(r"ExcelFile.xls")
ws= wb.worksheets('First')

### This able to extract information:
test_range= ws.Range("A1") 
### Got issue AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Find':
test_range= ws.Range.Find("Series ID") 
print(test_range.value)
```

Does it mean `Range.Find` method does not supported in win32 package or I point it with the wrong existing module?

Comment: The easiest way is to loop through every cell in the range, it would be quite the same speed.

Comment: *ha!* I was just about to quote you @Vityata from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47204701/find-range-of-filled-contents-in-excel-worksheet#comment81359344_47204995   for @ user2851376  (I don't actually have a clue about python but it seemed like you knew what you were talking about)

Comment: @ashleedawg - funny, using the api is way better, indeed! Will check whether it would work with .Find, but it should!

Comment: @Vityata Thanks for the feedback. Could you have a better suggestion on this? Cause sometimes the excel file will have more than 20k rows. If go through the 20k rowsX 20columns it will affect the performance is it? FYI, the excel file is from vendor which is we would never know what is the exact total of cells in the excel file. Hope can suggest the most dynamic way and fastest performance. Plus reliable too. :)

Comment: @ashleedawg - strange, but I cannot access the `api.Find()` now. Still, standard looping is always an option.

Comment: @ashleedawg - after 4 coffees and some water I can think again! See the third answer, it is exactly following the API idea :)

Comment: This question is [being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/368756/should-i-unite-3-answers-in-one)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bonus answer: if you are a fan of the Excel API (10x to @ashleedawg comment), you can use it directly through xlwings:

```
import xlwings as xw

bookName = r'C:\somePath\hello.xlsx'
sheetName = 'Sheet1'

wb = xw.Book(bookName)
sht = wb.sheets[sheetName]

myCell = wb.sheets[sheetName].api.UsedRange.Find('test')
print('---------------')
print (myCell.address)
input()
```

Thus an input like this:

[image]

Nicely returns this:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to use your code but hit one error in "xw.Book". **OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application** FYI, I'm open other excel file while testing. Then, after I close all the excel application, no error occur. Is it was one of the limitation xlwings?

Comment: I found my answer. Just for sharing, I amend code from `test_range= ws.Range.Find("Series ID")` to `test_range= ws.UsedRange.Find("Series ID")` able to extract exactly like xlwings. As I can't share the answer then I will mark this as the best answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So with the first part of the code some Excel file with random-like numbers is generated:

```
import xlsxwriter
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell
import xlrd    

#First part of the code, used only to create some Excel file with data

wbk = xlsxwriter.Workbook('hello.xlsx')
wks = wbk.add_worksheet()
i = -1

for x in range(1, 1000, 11):
    i+=1
    cella = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 0) #0,0 is A1!
    cellb = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 1)
    cellc = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 2)
    #print (cella)
    wks.write(cella,x)
    wks.write(cellb,x*3)
    wks.write(cellc,x*4.5)
myPath= r'C:\Desktop\hello.xlsx'
wbk.close()

#SecondPart of the code

for sh in xlrd.open_workbook(myPath).sheets():  
    for row in range(sh.nrows):
        for col in range(sh.ncols):
            myCell = sh.cell(row, col)
            print(myCell)
            if myCell.value == 300.0:
                print('-----------')
                print('Found!')
                print(xl_rowcol_to_cell(row,col))
                quit()
```

With the second part of the code, the real "Searching" starts. In this case, we are searching for `300`, which is actually one of the generated values from the first part of the code:

[image]

So, python starts looping through rows and columns, comparing the values with `300`. If the value is found, it writes `Found` and stops searching:

[image]

This code can be actually re-written, with making the second part as a function (def).

Comment: Note, you don't need to use `xl_rowcol_to_cell()` to get a cell range for `write()`, it can take `(row, col)` as parameters. See the [XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html).

Comment: @jmcnamara - Thanks, will definitely take a better look later!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it with a function, this is a way to do it - `defCell` is the name of the function.

```
import xlsxwriter
import os
import xlrd    
import time 
from xlsxwriter.utility import xl_rowcol_to_cell

def findCell(sh, searchedValue):
    for row in range(sh.nrows):
        for col in range(sh.ncols):
            myCell = sh.cell(row, col)
            if myCell.value == searchedValue:
                return xl_rowcol_to_cell(row, col)
    return -1

myName = 'hello.xlsx'
wbk = xlsxwriter.Workbook(myName)
wks = wbk.add_worksheet()
i = -1

for x in range(1, 1000, 11):
    i+=1
    cella = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 0) #0,0 is A1!
    cellb = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 1)
    cellc = xl_rowcol_to_cell(i, 2)
    wks.write(cella,x)
    wks.write(cellb,x*3)
    wks.write(cellc,x*4.5)
myPath= os.getcwd()+"\\"+myName

searchedValue = 300
for sh in xlrd.open_workbook(myPath).sheets():  
    print(findCell(sh, searchedValue))
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

It produces this after running it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes win32com can do the exact same range.find() function. The problem with your code is you didnt specify what is the range. `Range` has no `Find` attribute.

```
test_range= ws.Range.Find("Series ID") #<-----no range specified
```

Below is the correct use of `Range` and `Find`

```
import win32com.client as client

excel= client.dynamic.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.visible= True

wb= excel.workbooks.open(r"ExcelFile.xls")
ws= wb.worksheets('First')

test_range= ws.Range("A1")    
### example if you want to find out the column of search result
ResultColumn= test_range.Find("Series ID").Column 
print(str(ResultColumn))
```